# Show $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^p f(nx) = 0$ exists in the distributional sense

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be periodic, with period $2\pi$ and have mean zero ($\int^{2\pi}_0 f(x)dx =0$).  Show that for any positive integer $p$ the following limit is valid in the distributional sense.
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^p f(nx)= 0$$

What I have so far is that 
 $$   \int^\infty_{-\infty} n^p f(nx)\phi(x)dx=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}n^p\int^{2\pi k+2\pi}_{2\pi k} f(nx)\phi(x)dx  $$

Using $y=x-2\pi k$ and $dy=dx$,

$$ =\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}n^{p}\int^{2\pi}_{0} f(ny+2\pi k n)\phi(y+2\pi k )dy $$

by periodicity of $f$, this becomes

$$ =\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}n^{p}\int^{2\pi n}_{0} f(ny)\phi(y+2\pi k )dy $$

Since $\phi\in C^\infty_0$, there exist integers $a,b$ such that $\phi(y+2\pi k )=0\forall k<a,k>b$

$$ =\sum^{b}_{k=a}n^{p}\int^{2\pi n}_{0} f(ny)\phi(y+2\pi k )dy $$

I am unsure how to proceed further.  I suspect a Fourier series is involved.

Comment: What do you mean to have that first limit without an integral sign, but with the $dx$?

Comment: My mistake.  Fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to perform a change of variables $y=nx$?

You will obtain a series which is a function of $\phi$.  Then it is a matter of using that function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c({\mathbb R})$.  (Though it might not be the best approach).

We could use a Fourier series expansion for $f$, right?  In this case, $c_0=0$ where $c_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) dt.$  It might work, and it holds for all $t\in {\mathbb R}$.

Let's not forget that, in this case, for any $p>0$ we have

$$\sum |k|^p |c_k|^2 < \infty.$$

I think that performing integration by parts $p+1$ times you manage to obtain a function $F(x)$ which satisfies the same as $f$, and the solution follows. Thus the factor $n^p$ is no longer trouble (using that $\phi$ is of compact support, of course).

We simply, for $p$ fixed, reduce to the case where $p=0$, which we have observed presents no trouble.

---

We may assume wlog that $\phi(x)$ has its support contained within an open interval within $[-\pi, \pi]$ (simply, choose $N\in {\mathbb N}$ big enough and take $f$ to be $2\pi N$-periodic.)

Now, write $$f(x)=\sum_{0\neq k\in {\mathbb Z}} c_k e^{ikt}.$$  The desired integral is of the form

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum c_k e^{ikt} \phi(x)\ dx.$$

Now, let us concentrate on the individual integral

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{iknt} \phi(x) \ dx,$$

and perform $p+1$ times integration by parts.  Use that $\phi^{(m)}(\pi)=\phi^{(m)}(-\pi)=0$ for all $m\geq 0$ (by construction), and there is no division by zero.  You obtain a denominator of the form $(nk)^{p+1}$, and the desired result follows.

The sum is perfectly OK, by the above.

To prove convergence in the space of tempered distributions, you integrate by parts between $2\pi m$ and $2\pi m$ for sufficiently big m, and will be able to use the topology on $S({\mathbb R})$ with the terms appearing (up to $p$ derivatives of $\phi$).

Comment: This gives us yn=t ndy=dt

$$ =\sum^{b}_{k=a}n^{p-1}\int^{2\pi}_{0} f(t)\phi(n^{-1}t+2\pi k )dt $$

For $p=1$ this is no problem but for any greater $p$ we may have issues.

Comment: True.  How about a Fourier series expansion? We have extra info on the growth of the coefficients (it's added to the answer).

Comment: The point about the Fourier series expansion is, you can fully see that the function $F(x)$ that is periodic, $C^\infty$, satisfies that $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^pF=f$, chosen such that $\int_0^{2\pi} F(x)\ dx=0$ corresponds to the case you've already solved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $F$ must have the same zero mean property.  Or what we can choose it to be so?

Comment: I have added all details.  You just have to make sure you integrate on a sufficiently big interval so that $\phi$ is identically zero close to the boundary.

Comment: The case for tempered distributions is now added.